# Problem while reading urls from csv file and getting the output in csv file as well

Tags: python, csv, asynchronous, beautifulsoup, aiohttp

The below code is supposed to return the status code and model number of few products from the website https://www.selexion.be/. It was working fine when i put all the urls in urls array inside the code but when i am fetching url form csv file i am getting this error.

Also i want to store the output url, status code and model number in an array and want to flush(`.flush()` & `os.fsync()`) that array to csv file when all the link's status code and model number are fetched. Because i am getting the output in terminal but i want the output as well in a csv file.

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Zandrio> & C:/Users/Zandrio/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "c:/Users/Zandrio/Documents/Advanced Project/Selexion.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Zandrio/Documents/Advanced Project/Selexion.py", line 49, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\Zandrio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Zandrio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 612, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:/Users/Zandrio/Documents/Advanced Project/Selexion.py", line 41, in main
    await asyncio.gather(*(worker(f'w{index}', url, session)
  File "c:/Users/Zandrio/Documents/Advanced Project/Selexion.py", line 32, in worker
    response = await session.get(url, headers=header)
  File "C:\Users\Zandrio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 380, in _request
    url = URL(str_or_url)
  File "C:\Users\Zandrio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yarl\__init__.py", line 149, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Constructor parameter should be str")
TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str
```

Code:

```
import asyncio
import csv
import aiohttp
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = []

try:

 with open('C:\\Users\\Zandrio\\Documents\\Advanced Project\\input_links.csv','r', newline='') as csvIO:
    urls = list(csv.reader(csvIO))

except FileNotFoundError:
    pass


header = {
'Host': 'www.selexion.be',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'TE': 'Trailers'
}


async def worker(name, url, session):
    response = await session.get(url, headers=header)
    html = await response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml').select_one('.title-options span:first-of-type').text
    print(f'URL: {url} - {response.status} - {soup}')


async def main():
     async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            await asyncio.gather(*(worker(f'w{index}', url, session)
                            for index, url in enumerate(urls)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start
    print(f'Executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says its a type error, meaning a function returns a parameter of type A, but type B was passed.

```
TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str
```

In the line

`await asyncio.gather(*(worker(f'w{index}', url, session)`

what is the type of url? You can find out with

```
type(url)
```

or by running your debugger.

What happens when you flip those two lines

```
 await asyncio.gather(*(worker(f'w{index}', url, session)
                            for index, url in enumerate(urls)))
```

I don't see where url comes from otherwise.

Comment: Well, the urls are of list type. When i used to put all the url inside of code ::\Users\Zandrio> & C:/Users/Zandrio/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "c:/Users/Zandrio/Documents/Advanced Project/IO.py"
[['https://www.selexion.be/nl/pr/microsoft-surface-laptop-2-i5-256gb-plat', 'https://www.selexion.be/nl/pr/lenovo-yoga-s730-13iwl-1', 'https://www.selexion.be/nl/pr/panasonic-uhd-tx65fx780e']]
<class 'list'>

Comment: the type of the elements in the list is the question here. E.g. what's the type of the first element of the url list?

Have you tried the other suggestions I have mentioned?

Comment: the first element in the url list is <class 'tuple'>

Comment: a string is expected a tuple is given - that might be the problem. What's in the tuple?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HgGMw-vMLRdNbp2srE0nUVDW1zXs0IvN?usp=sharing   . Check out this code it is working perfectly with the class tuple.But this is an url array that i have to write inside the code, have a look.

Comment: these files don't have extensions and are thus expected to by binaries, you can easily share code (with syntax highlighting!) using https://gist.github.com/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Luciferianism/e9cf047b1444769971839b58e8d0f73c